# jQuery colorbox. Custom closing animation

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I wanted to override default animation of colorbox popup. I've easily managed to slide it out from any position on the page, that creates an illusion that it's poping out from inside an element, and user can see where the data is coming from.

```
   onOpen: function () {
            $('#colorbox').css({ 'left': $(element).offset().left + 'px', 'top': $(element).offset().top + 'px' });
        }
```

Now, it works when it gets opened. At closing time it just fades out. But I want it disappear the same way as it opens. I'm trying to put something like this into onCleanup:

```
onCleanup: function () {
            $('#colorbox').animate({ 'left': $(element).offset().left + 'px', 'top': $(element).offset().top + 'px', width: '0px', height: '0px' }, { queue: false });

        }
```

but it doesn't work. It still just fades out. Help me please.

Comment: On the developers site it says that for customizing ColorBox it's better to use the event hooks. 'cbox_cleanup' triggers as the close method begins. Source: http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/

Comment: can you show me a code snippet?

Comment: It's right underneath the explanation on the site... `$(document).bind('cbox_cleanup', function(){
        alert('hello world');
});`

Comment: No... doesn't work. I mean it throws the alert, but if I try to manipulate the colorobox itself, doesn't do nothing. Still just fades off.